# Slow AC Wireless Speeds

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am experiencing poor wireless speeds and am looking for help tracking down the culprit. My router is a Netgear C7000 configured for 5GHz with 80MHz channels (clean air). Computers on the network running AC wireless equipment get an external speedtest of ~250mbps. Internally, speedtest via iperf yields ~50-80mbps.

Tests:
iperf: AC computer --wireless--> router --wireless--> N computer = 50 mbps
AC computer --wired (1gbps link)--> router  --wireless--> N computer = 100mbps
AC computer --wireless--> router --wired (1gbps link)--> N computer = 80mbps
AC computer --wired (1gbps link)--> router --wired (1gbps link)--> N computer = 987mbps

So the culprit comes down to wireless, but not isolated to either machine (i.e. the problem is at the router). Any recommendations for things to try to improve performance?

And just for the record, if I turn on the 2.4GHz wireless and connect both machines to it (limited to N), iperf is 17mbps.

Comment: Just to be clear, what exactly do you mean when you say "(clean air)"?

Comment: Meaning no one else is using the 5ghz channel (or any adjacent channels). Also, to be clear, both computers are close to the router (10-15 feet) with no obstructions.

Comment: Did you use a real spectrum analyzer (shows all RF energy on the band, not just Wi-Fi) to verify that, or did you just use a Wi-Fi scanner (only shows Wi-Fi networks)?

Comment: There are a lot of different flavors of N and AC that greatly affect speed. At least tell us how many spatial streams each client supports. Better yet, tell us what your wireless chipsets are.

Comment: 987 is literally impossibly high for gigabit Ethernet unless you're using jumbo frames. For TCP over IPv4 with standard 1500 byte frames, the theoretical max is about 942 mbps. What size frames are you using for that wired test? Are you doing TCP or UDP?